# C++ read number string and capture specific position character as int

Tags: c++, string, int, assign

I need my program to read a string of numbers input by the user and then assign each number to an int variable:

94715 is input by the user as string

then

```
a=9
b=4
c=7
d=1
e=5
```

so I can

```
if (a < b),  c*d+e, a-e, etc
```

I've searched some commands (getline, string.substr(ind,n), getc, fgetc, atoi, etc) I know I'm close but I can't find examples of exactly what I'm looking for.

The simplest and most direct way I've found is

```
stringstream convert(string1);
convert>>variable;
```

but it converts the whole string, if there was a way to add an ind position in it like

```
string1.substr(0,1)
```

that'd do the trick...

Comment: So the numbers should be single decimal digits? Remember the fact that `char c = '0'; c - '0' == 0`.

Comment: Are there any limitations to the input? e.g, the user must enter exactly 5 digits, etc...

Comment: Read a single unsigned integer, ensure the value is in the range [00000, 100000) and extract the digits (modulo 10 and divide by 10). For leading zeros you have to read a string of five characters and convert via istingstream.

Comment: Alternative: Read character by character and convert each (might be better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as this:

```
std::string num = "94715";
size_t i = 0;
assert( num.length() > 4 );
int a = num[i++] - '0';
int b = num[i++] - '0';
int c = num[i++] - '0';
int d = num[i++] - '0';
int e = num[i++] - '0';
```

note: this may not work properly on systems not using ACII encoding, but it is unlikely you would hit such problem.

Comment: simple, easy, fast. Thanks a lot!! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
int number = 9544; 
int vector[10]; // you can make it as big as you want or simply use std::vector
int position = 0;
while (number != 0)
{
    vector[position++] = number % 10; // this assigns the last digit
    number = number / 10; // remove the last digit
}
for(int i=0; i<position; i++)
    std::cout << vector[i]; // this will print 4459
```

Now you have your number's digits inside an int vector.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This example uses chars because a string is still a char array.
This is for if you are on Windows. Just input and press the `enter` key.
Like Dieter Lücking suggested, it does this character by character.

It uses `kbhit()` and `getch()` found in `conio.h` to process single characters.
Then it multiplys the characters with appropiate position to get full integer.
And then it stores them in the array `digitArray[ ]`, and assigns them to `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` or `e` after. Now you can do whatever with `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` and `e`.

Here is some code to demonstrate.

```
   // Re: Now it is just clunky 
   //         one                ten              hundred              thousand
   //          1                  2                  3                    4
   //digitn=digitArray[3]*1 + digitArray[2]*10 +digitArray[1]*100 +digitArray[0]*1000

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int digit=0,digitInput=0;
int digitArray[10]={0},digitn;
int numberOfInputDigits=7;
void SplitIntoDigits(void);
int a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0,e=0,f=0;


int main(){

    system("color 1F");     //Blue background    
    while(1){

       cout<<"\nPlease enter number. Max Input is  "<<numberOfInputDigits<<" individual digits \n";
       cout<<"or press enter when done  \n>" ;       

       memset(digitArray,0,sizeof(digitArray));
       a=0;b=0;c=0;d=0;e=0;f=0;

       SplitIntoDigits();

       //cout<<"\n"<<digitArray[7]="<<digitArray[7];
       cout<<"\n\n";

       a = digitArray[0];
       b = digitArray[1];
       c = digitArray[2];
       d = digitArray[3];
       e = digitArray[4];
       f = digitArray[5];

       cout<<"a = "<< a <<"\n";
       cout<<"b = "<< b <<"\n";
       cout<<"c = "<< c <<"\n";
       cout<<"d = "<< d <<"\n";
       cout<<"e = "<< e <<"\n";
       cout<<"f = "<< f <<"\n";


       cout<<"\n\n The whole combined int number is "<<digitn<<"\n\n";

    }


    return 0;
}


/*********************************
 *                               *
 ********************************/

void SplitIntoDigits(void){
   digitArray[0]=0;
   digitArray[1]=0;
   digit=0;
   digitInput=0;

   while((digit<numberOfInputDigits)){
       if (kbhit()){

           digitInput=getch();
           if (digitInput==27) exit(0);

           if ((digitInput>47) && (digitInput<59)) {
             digitArray[digit]=(unsigned char)digitInput-48;
             digit++;

             cout<<digitInput-48;

           }
           if (digitInput==13)  { digitn=digitArray[0]; break; }
       }
   }

   switch(digit) {
       case 0:
       case 1:
            digitn=digitArray[0]*1 ;
       break;

       case 2:
            digitn= digitArray[1]*1  +digitArray[0]*10  ;
       break;

       case 3:
            digitn=  digitArray[2]*1+digitArray[1]*10 +digitArray[0]*100  ;
       break;

       case 4:
             digitn=digitArray[3]*1+digitArray[2]*10+digitArray[1]*100+digitArray[0]*1000 ;
       break;

       case 5:
             digitn=digitArray[4]*1+digitArray[3]*10+digitArray[2]*100+digitArray[1]*1000+digitArray[0]*10000 ;
       break;

       case 6:
             digitn=digitArray[5]*1+digitArray[4]*10+digitArray[3]*100+digitArray[2]*1000+digitArray[1]*10000 
                   +digitArray[0]*100000;
       break;


       case 7:
             digitn=digitArray[6]*1+digitArray[5]*10+digitArray[4]*100+digitArray[3]*1000+digitArray[2]*10000 
                   +digitArray[1]*100000 +digitArray[0]*1000000;
       break;


       case 8:
             digitn=digitArray[7]*1+digitArray[6]*10+digitArray[5]*100+digitArray[4]*1000+digitArray[3]*10000 
                   +digitArray[2]*100000 +digitArray[1]*1000000+digitArray[0]*10000000;
       break;

       case 9:
             digitn=digitArray[8]*1+digitArray[7]*10+digitArray[6]*100+digitArray[5]*1000+digitArray[4]*10000 
                   +digitArray[3]*100000 +digitArray[2]*1000000+digitArray[1]*10000000 +digitArray[0]*100000000;
       break;


   }


  // if (digitInput!=13)  digitn=digitArray[3]*1+digitArray[2]*10+digitArray[1]*100+digitArray[0]*1000 ;
   //cout<<("\n%i\n\n",digitn);
}

/*********************************
 *                               *
 ********************************/
```

Comment: No way: `using namespace std;` and using `global variables`. This is a bad answer.